# React - Variable being printed as text instead of HTML tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have this function that is supposed to input a div and class before and after every 3 items in an array.

Here is the code

```
  const board_thing = squares.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <>
        {index % 3 === 0 ? "<div className='board-row'>" : ''}
        <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)}/>
        {index % 3 === 2 ? '</div>' : ''}
      </>
    )
  })
```

and this is the type of output I want to achieve

```
      <div className='board-row'>
        <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)}/>
        <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)}/>
        <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)}/>
      </div>
      <div className='board-row'>
        <Square value={squares[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)}/>
        <Square value={squares[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)}/>
        <Square value={squares[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)}/>
      </div>
      <div className='board-row'>
        <Square value={squares[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)}/>
        <Square value={squares[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)}/>
        <Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)}/>
      </div>
```

But this is the output I'm getting.

[image]

Comment: It's because you're adding quotes at the `<div>` element, just remove the quotes and close the `<div/>`, something like that: `{index % 3 === 0 ? <div className='board-row' /> : null}` (better to use `null` instead of empty string)

Comment: @Mathiasfc - You can't just remove the quotes, because you can't optionally start or end an element like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with JSX, you aren't working in HTML. You can't optionally start a tag, then later optionally close it. Instead, [chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) your array into groups of three, then output the chunks:

```
// This is using one of the many answers to the chunking question linked above,
// use whichever you like best. You may want to memoize the result.
const chunks = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 3) {
    // Remember the items original index, since we need it for `handleClick`
    chunks.push(array.slice(i, i + 3).map((item, index) => ({
        item,
        index: i + index
    }));
}
const board_thing = chunks.map((chunk) => (
    <div key={/*???*/} className="board-row">
        {chunk.map(({item, index}) => (
            <Square key={/*???*/} value={item} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(index)}/>
        ))}
    </div>
));
```

Note the placeholders I've left for keys. You need to provide keys, and [generally shouldn't use indexes for them](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#rules-of-keys:%7E:text=You%20might%20be%20tempted%20to%20use%20an%20item%E2%80%99s%20index%20in%20the%20array%20as%20its%20key).

Answer (score 0):

You must send element directly and not string of elements
Also, you can refactor the code to send the elements 3 by 3 instead of 1 by 1

```js
const board_thing = squares.reduce((subArray, item) => {
if (subArray[-1].length < 3) {
    subArray[-1].push(item)
}
else {
    subArray.push([item])
}
return subArray
},[[]]).map((subArray, index) => {
    return (
      <div className='board-row'>
        {subArray.map((item, subIndex) => <Square value={item} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(index*3+subIndex)}/>)}
      </div>
    )
  })
```